# Javascript: Light up where mouse is; rest is dark

Tags: javascript

I think it has been a while but I think I remember seeing a javascript feature where the whole screen is black and where you mouse is it shows what is under the black. Anyone have an idea of how to do this or what I am talking about?

Comment: This? http://home.comcast.net/~vonholdt/test/flashlight.htm

Comment: Found the answer myself finally; http://home.comcast.net/~jscheuer1/side/flashlight/

Comment: That's pretty awesome :)

Comment: I think the trick is in jpg file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the source of the page and it is not too difficult to understand. What they are doing is ***setting a background image*** for the body tag and then ***adjusting the background position on mousemove*** using the x and y mouse co-ordinates.

**Note**

They are using ***jQuery*** to do this. You can do this without using a js library also.

Comment: The 2nd example at http://home.comcast.net/~jscheuer1/side/flashlight/ does something different too.

Comment: @adamantium, I don't know what happened. I `-1` the other answer, not yours. It was great, but now it won't let me change it. Can you edit so I can change my vote?

Comment: Thanks! I am so glad you said something! I promise I clicked on the other answer :) Blame the JS... +1 for great answer

Comment: It wasn't a blame, just curious about the reason for the down vote.:-)

Answer (score -1):

This is more case of a CSS change on mouse over in javascript. Try [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/legacy/beyond/javascript/backgroundjavascript.html) example if this suits you

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants.